# What is the design reason template overloading of structs is not allowed in C++20?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

In answer to my previous question I learned that C++ 20 concepts do **not** allow overloading on struct template arguments, for example this does not work:

```
#include <concepts>

template <std::integral>
struct S{

};
template <std::floating_point>
struct S{
};
```

For curious clang error is something like, but that does not matter since I know C++ standard does not allow this code to work:

> type constraint differs in template redeclaration

I find this nonworking way of writing templates very natural so I wonder was this ever considered, and if so why it was rejected during standardization?

P.S. this seems to work in C++20, but I find it much uglier

```
#include <concepts>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
requires std::integral<T> || std::floating_point<T>
struct S{

};
template <std::integral T>
struct S<T>{
    static constexpr char msg[] = "i";

};
template <std::floating_point T>
struct S<T>{
    static constexpr char msg[] = "fp";
};

int main() {
    std::cout <<  S<char>::msg << std::endl;
    std::cout <<  S<double>::msg << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: The "ugly" bit is unnecessary. The primary can be no more than `template <typename T> struct S;` https://godbolt.org/z/zq534r66e

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica but then error messages are garbage, right, since somebody deep in the code might want to use ::msg, and that is what all "good" templates have?

Comment: I don't understand what hand wavy "garbage" means.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica I think error msg for https://godbolt.org/z/P3jKfq3oM is worse than error msg for https://godbolt.org/z/shGsT3sqY

Comment: I'd argue this is purely subjective. I don't think either of them will obviate the need to open the template definitions, and so the specializations and constraints will be read and understood either way.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica yeah, IDK :) I think too early to tell... ATM I am personally disappointed how currently concept error messages are mostly useless(when I mess up something in ranges code).

Comment: We were all told concepts improve error messages. But it is a false messiah, I'm afraid. Deeply nested SFINAE failures are still deeply nested and incomprehensible, whether they are checked by the old hacks or a concept.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Don't *have* deeply nested errors. Do all the checks at the top level.

Comment: The first code lives in an open world where `S<void*>` specialisation can be legitimately added. The error message tells you that such specialisation is not visible from where you are trying to use it. The compiler cannot reasonably tell you *why* it is not visible. The second code lives in a closed world where `S<void*>` cannot possibly exist due to constraints, and the error message tells you which constraint. These are two different worlds, and you get an error message according to the world you choose.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. true,  I never considered the aspect of allowing users to extend my precious template...

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica hmm just require that `std::ranges::size` is callable for the supplied type, or I don't understand something?

Comment: Isn't this just the normal template specialization rules? It has been like this for a very long time afaik...

Comment: @JHBonarius not sure what you exactly mean, but I know there was difference beetween functions and structs in C++17. But I see nothing preventing the C++20 from allowing stuff I am asking about. Obviously I know very little about templates and grammar so it is quite possible I am very wrong. :)

Comment: With your first piece of code, you're re-declaring the template. Which is allowed, as long as the type-constraint is the same (just like the error tells you). If you want to have different specializations of a template for different types, you need [template specialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization)

Comment: @JHBonarius I know, my question is about why C++ choose this design, it is very subjective, but I find my code more readable... Obviously people might disagree, but I still feel this question probably has a specific answer, and is not opinion based...

Comment: Wow... so back to the beginning 1989... You could ask [Bjarne on Twitter](https://twitter.com/stroustrup?lang=en). haha. It likely has to do with resolution of the template. There has to be a way for the compiler to resolve multiple declarations.

Answer (score 10):

C++ has never had overloading for **classes** or class templates.  Classes of course have no parameters with which an overload might be chosen, but neither can one write

```
template<class> struct A {};
template<int> struct A {};
```

even though for every *template-id* it is obvious which would pertain (`A<int>` *vs.* `A<1>`).  There are several reasons for this restriction:

1. It’s impossible to write **generic** code that uses one of the above overloads chosen at instantiation time: for every `A<…>`, whether the argument is a type or a value is fixed even if it’s dependent.  (This wouldn’t be true if the overloads were `template<int&>` and `template<float&>`, of course.)
2. Templates are occasionally mentioned **without** any template arguments, and there’s no syntax for selecting one where both might apply.  One such context is as a template template argument (that might be of the generic `template<class...> class` variety); another is CTAD.
3. Some **ADL**-like mechanisms would be necessary to support the case of overloading a class template for an application type after generic code that used the template(s).
4. It would not in general be possible to determine to which overload a **partial specialization** pertained.

The C++20 behavior is just the continuation of this model; it’s not hard to add a generic

```
template<class> struct S;  // undefined
```

to serve as an umbrella over partial specializations declared as

```
template<std::integral I>
struct S<I> {};
template<std::floating_point F>
struct S<F> {};
```

Comment: quick Q: are you sure this is correct, it looks like you are mixing NTTP and "normal"  templates: template<auto> struct S;  // undefined

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: Sorry: I wrote it right at first and then got confused by the concept syntax.

Answer (score 6):

Template argument deduction does not work with an **explicit** specialization of a class template (in comparison to a function template). This has nothing to do with concepts per se. You will need the `template<>` keyword and the `<T>` parameter.

I do not know of and cannot find any standard proposal further shortening this.

In the following code especially the primary definition of `S` got much shorter than the working version in the question.

```
#include <concepts>

template <typename T>
concept Number = std::integral<T> || std::floating_point<T>;


template <Number T>
struct S;

template <std::integral T>
struct S<T>{
};

template <std::floating_point T>
struct S<T>{
};
```

The above code compiles and works.

By using `Number` the first line of the error message for instantiating `S` with e.g. `std::string` is:

`error: template constraint failure for 'template<class T>  requires  Number<T> struct S'`

Which is easy to understand and to the point (with more detailing information in the following lines about `std::string` not being an `integral || floating_point`). So it is possible to build levels of error messages for wrong instantiations (e.g. you could define your own `integral` concept which lists the allowed integer types).

Comment: I think `Number` is not a good name. In the std lib we have [`is_arithmetic`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_arithmetic) which does exactly the same, so the proper name would be "arithmetic". IMHO this should actually already have been a part of the concepts library. And the concept should be `template < class T >
concept arithmetic = std::is_arithmetic_v<T>;`.

Comment: @JHBonarius because of the ordering rules, you want concepts built from other concepts, not traits, as much as possible.

Comment: @Caleth ok, I'm just saying that we already have a trait `is_arithmetic`. So we should have a concept `arithmetic`. If it was standardized, we wouldn't have discussions on how it should be implemented, as that std lib already does that for us. Also, when using traits, if you wrote your own artihmetic type, you could then only write your own overload for `std::is_arithmetic<MyType>`. But that's off topic.

Comment: In this limited example you could choose `Arithmetic` as name in relation to `is_arithmetic`. But on the other hand, concepts are not so much about the std lib internals as about the semantics of your program. They among other advantages lead to good error messages. An identifier should be chosen that it is understandable by the users of your concept - yourself, your coworkers or the users of your library. (The same as is the case for function and type names). Even if there are existing identical concepts, it could make sense to introduce a new one with a telling name.